# Fail to register for remote notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, remote-notifications

After updating Xcode version to 8.0 I'm getting this error. When trying to register for remote notifications I can see in my logs like this

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}, no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application
```

I tried after found some Stack Overflow answers related to my question but not able to solve this.

1.Created new Provisional Profile

2.Deleted and re-installed app

3.Tried to set provisional profile manually.

Any of the above not helped me to solve.

Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. After some non-obvious searching I found out that under iOS 10 and Xcode 8, you now need to enable the Push Notifications capability for your target.

In Xcode, select your target. Go to the Capabilities tab. Enable the Push Notifications capability.

Comment: Oh my badness! I missed that thing. Thank you so much for saving my day @rmaddy

Comment: Such an easy fix. Just had to click a "fix issue" button right there in the Capabilities. Just had to know where to look. Thanks for saving me some time! Cheers!